# Docker VM disk size on Windows 10

Tags: windows, postgresql, docker

I'm running Docker on Windows 10 and got an error today that it's full.  I just have 1 image (postgresql 10.1-alpine 38.2MB) and have removed everything else.  I also ran `docker system prune --force` which freed up 0MB.

I've read that it is (or was) a known issue on Windows 10, that deleting containers leaves stuff behind.  However, if I go into my `%USERPROFILE%\.docker\machine\machines\default` I find the VM disk file (`disk.vmdk`) that's 18GB in size!

Aside from uninstalling and reinstalling, is there any way to reduce the size of this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also prune the unused volumes, these consume a lot of space.

```
docker system prune --force --volumes
```

Comment: That was it!  Freed up over 14GB of space